# How can we handle datetime exceptions in postgreSQL 9.6.11 code?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, exception, postgresql-9.6

[image]I have included the `invalid_datetime_format` exception which is required in my code and tried to test it out. I tried to throw an error by giving improper `Column3` format (i.e timestamp column) which will trigger this exception in the output.(Actual format: `2019-11-10 07:10:55.865000`; Format I have given to catch the exception: `2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000`).

**My requirement is that the code should give the error message using `SQLERM` and print `Datetime format is not valid` as mentioned in the code**. But, its unable to catch the exception that I have provided in the code. Instead, it gives

> ```
> ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000"  SQL state: 22007.
> ```

I have posted the image where I've added the records to the test_table through test_function. I need my code to show me the exception that I've included in the code instead of showing the error that I've mentioned above. Please help me out. 
You will be able to replicate the test_function and test_table from the below code. You just need to create them under test_schema in pgadmin.

```
--Table that needs to be populated when the function is called.
--Table schema mentioned below
--Create a test_schema under a database in postgreSQL and then create this test_table and test_function under it to replicate the error.

CREATE TABLE test_schema.test_table
(
id SERIAL,
Column1 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
Column2 date NOT NULL,
Column3 timestamp without time zone,
Column4 character varying COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
Column5 timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
Column6 timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
CONSTRAINT pk_filename_Column1 PRIMARY KEY (Column1, Column2)
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE test_schema.test_table
OWNER to postgres;

--Beginning of function

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_schema.test_function(
Column1 character varying,
Column2 date,
Column3 timestamp without time zone)
RETURNS character varying
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'

COST 100
VOLATILE 

AS $BODY$
declare

isExists         boolean;
message          character varying;
err_context      text;

begin
    SET timezone TO 'America/New_York';

insert into test_schema.test_table 
(
Column1, 
Column2, 
Column3, 
Column4
)
values 
(
Column1,
Column2,
CAST(TO_CHAR(Column3::timestamp , 'YYYY-MM-dd HH:MI:SS.US') as TIMESTAMP),
'xyz'
);
return 'Successful';

--Handling the required exception 

EXCEPTION 

WHEN invalid_datetime_format THEN
message = SQLERRM||E'\n'||'Datetime format is not valid';
return message;

WHEN OTHERS THEN
GET STACKED DIAGNOSTICS err_context = PG_EXCEPTION_CONTEXT;
message = 'Error: '||SQLERRM||E'\n'||err_context;
return message;
end;
$BODY$;
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error.

Comment: You need to create a table with records in it and call this function to reproduce the error. I'll add the table schema here in couple of minutes.

Comment: I mean, I did that.

Comment: I have made few changes. Can you please check it now?

Comment: If you add some data and a call so that it becomes a self-contained test case that reproduces the problem, that would help.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I've made changes for you to replicate my problem. Please run them to add records and try to see the exception problem I've mentioned in my question.

Comment: Works like a charm. But then `column3` is a timestamp, so the cast will always succeed.

Comment: How will my exception i.e. WHEN invalid_datetime_format THEN
message = SQLERRM||E'\n'||'Datetime format is not valid';
return message;  will work in the code is my actual question. I want the code to handle the datetime exception by giving SQLERM and 'Datatime format is invalid' instead of ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000"  SQL state: 22007 Character: 70. CAn you check for it?

Comment: You'd have to come up with code that makes the problem reproducible.

Comment: **You need to change the Column3 format to 2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000 while inserting the record through test_function into the test_table to reproduce the error.**
I need my code to catch the exception mentioned in the code instead of it throwing the error  **invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "2019-11-10-07.10.55.865000"  SQL state: 22007**

Comment: First provide code that reproduces the behavior.